# Insert hyperlink into text using django

Tags: python, django, hyperlink

I have a variable 'text' in python which contains a very long string. And I have a dict whose key is a word/group of words and value is a url. I need to display this variable 'text' using django, creating hyperlink of all the words/group of words from text which are also there in dict. The link is already stored as value in the dict.

text = "taj mahal is in india"

my_dict = { 'taj mahal':'url1', 'india':'url2' }

Display this text using django where 'taj mahal' and 'india' are hyperlinks to url1 and url2 respectively.
I tried to use urlize, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `replace()` on the `text` variable:

```
>>> text = "taj mahal is in india"
>>> my_dict = { 'taj mahal':'url1', 'india':'url2' }
>>> for key, value in my_dict.iteritems():
...     text = text.replace(key, value)
... 
>>> text
'url1 is in url2'
```

or:

```
>>> text = "taj mahal is in india"
>>> for key, value in my_dict.iteritems():
...     text = text.replace(key, '<a href="%s">key</a>' % value)
... 
>>> text
'<a href="url1">key</a> is in <a href="url2">key</a>'
```

If you want then to pass this `text` variable to the template, apply `safe` filter on it:

```
{{text|safe}}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: But the problem with this solution is, if I pass this variable text after replacing as you pointed to django inside template file like **{{text}}**, then it displays this exact thing on UI, i.e. _<a href="url1">key</a> is in <a href="url2">key</a>_  , instead of displaying the hyperlink.

Comment: The **|safe** thing was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton, alecxe :)